# ion-select popover not working Chrome 114

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework

I have a problem in ionic when try to open popover from ion-select interface=popover

My ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.2.6
   @angular/cli                  : 12.2.17
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0
```

the code from problem:

```
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-select interface="popover"  placeholder="Select fruit">
            <ion-select-option value="apples">Apples</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="oranges">Oranges</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="bananas">Bananas</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

the popover not open

I checked css and found display none but i dont know where is this property or how disabled:

```
[popover]:not(:popover-open):not(dialog[open]) {
    display: none;
}
```

I FOUND NOTES FROM CHROME 114 ABOUT POPOVER API
they used the property popover

Popover content

So in angular versión in the project is reflect this problem
since it also uses that property as indicated above

Comment: Having same issue since updating Google Chrome to 114 version. it was working fine before :(

Answer (score 26):

To resolve this, add the following code in the **global.scss**.

```css
ion-popover [popover]:not(:popover-open):not(dialog[open]) {
    display: contents;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me on ionic 5

Comment: This worked for me on ionic 7.1.1 , tho it still prints a "Found a 'popover' attribute with an invalid value." warning on the console

Answer (score 7):

This [bug](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/26643) is fixed already. You should update to [version 6.5.2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/releases/tag/v6.5.2) or later.

Answer (score 3):

The same problem with the ionic framework @ionic/angular 4.11.* can be fixed in the **global.scss** file with:

```
ion-popover .popover-viewport {
    display: contents;
}
```

**Warning:** this could have side effects

Answer (score 0):

`ion-popover [popover]:not(:popover-open):not(dialog[open]) { display: contents; }`

work at @ionic/angular": "^6.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree. Removing the lab was a poor choice. There are differences in how things work in mobile mode vs web mode, like the menu.